# Spawning more than 5 client requests on socket

Tags: python, sockets

If we bind a server socket like this:

```
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
server.bind((host,port)) 
server.listen(5)
```

and use something like select() and loop over and over each client connection until the client closes it to exchange messages while the loop (*for* here) is run concurrently we can make the exchange of server-client messages or client-client exchange concurrent. Can we?

But the problem as I've read is that the server cannot enqueue more than 5 clients to handle one by one;

What methods are there to actually run multiple such server instances, provided the criteris that multiple such server processes start to listen iff the clients queued up reach the level of 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 5 limitation you are concerned about is the size of listener backlog queue.  This is how many connections the system will hold in abeyance until it starts rejecting new connections.  When you `accept` a connection room is freed on that queue.  So as long as you accept your connections in a timely manner this is not really a concern under normal load conditions.  (BTW 5 is on the low side of things.  IIR the default max per process on linux, for instance, is 128.)

Answer (score 2):

When you receive a connection you can either spawn a thread/process to handle that connection.

On the main thread go back to listen for another connection

The 5 bit is the length of the list that are one hold.

Similar to a switchboard operator

Comment: I dont understand. When the server creates a client socket for that 'client' you mean to write this listener number decrements by 1? (5 goes down to 4?) even while the client socket is actively engaged?

Comment: When some one tries to connect to your server the counter is decremented from 5 to 4. When you accept the connection creating a "client socket" the counter is re-incremented to 5.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you misunderstood the function of the backlog argument.
The limit of 5 only applies to connection that are not already accepted.

Comment: I just asked to clarify that doubt in the comment section in the thread below